# creating spark data structure from multiline record

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read in retrosheet event file into spark.  The event file is structured as such.

```
id,TEX201403310
version,2
info,visteam,PHI
info,hometeam,TEX
info,site,ARL02
info,date,2014/03/31
info,number,0
info,starttime,1:07PM
info,daynight,day
info,usedh,true
info,umphome,joycj901
info,attendance,49031
start,reveb001,"Ben Revere",0,1,8
start,rollj001,"Jimmy Rollins",0,2,6
start,utlec001,"Chase Utley",0,3,4
start,howar001,"Ryan Howard",0,4,3
start,byrdm001,"Marlon Byrd",0,5,9
id,TEX201404010
version,2
info,visteam,PHI
info,hometeam,TEX
```

As you can see for each game the events loops back.

I've read the file into a RDD, and then via a second for loop added a key for each iteration, which appears to work.  But I was hoping to get some feedback on if there was a cleaning way to do this using spark methods.

```
logFile = '2014TEX.EVA'
event_data = (sc
              .textFile(logfile)
              .collect())

idKey = 0
newevent_list = []
for line in event_dataFile:
    if line.startswith('id'):
        idKey += 1
        newevent_list.append((idKey,line))
    else:
        newevent_list.append((idKey,line))

event_data = sc.parallelize(newevent_list)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PySpark [since version 1.1](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/09/17/spark-1-1-bringing-hadoop-inputoutput-formats-to-pyspark.html) supports [Hadoop Input Formats](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat).You can use `textinputformat.record.delimiter` option to use a custom format delimiter as below

```
from operator import itemgetter

retrosheet = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    '/path/to/retrosheet/file',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': '\nid,'}
)
(retrosheet
    .filter(itemgetter(1))
    .values()
    .filter(lambda x: x)
    .map(lambda v: (
        v if v.startswith('id') else 'id,{0}'.format(v)).splitlines()))
```

Since Spark 2.4 you can also read data into `DataFrame` using `text` reader

```
spark.read.option("lineSep", '\nid,').text('/path/to/retrosheet/file')
```

Comment: I just wanna say thank you, after days of exploring, finally I get your answer and it works fine for me, helps me out of the damned wholeTextFiles solution which consistently throws out OOM exception, thank you very much!