# PySpark: how to map by first item in array

Tags: python, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

My initial RDD is a list of blocks in which each block is a list of lines itself. So it's

> [infos_var1, infos_var2]

and each block is

> var_name, var_value1, var_value2, var_value3

The original data looks like this:

```
[[u'::852-YF-007\t',
  u'2016-05-10 00:00:00\t0',
  u'2016-05-09 23:59:00\t0',
  u'2016-05-09 23:42:00\t0'],
 [u'::852-YF-008\t',
  u'2016-05-10 00:00:00\t0',
  u'2016-05-09 23:59:00\t0',
  u'2016-05-09 23:42:00\t0']]
```

My question is how to use a map-function to extract the variable name (852-YF-007 and 852-YF-008) as key and as value the lines with the timestamp (here: 3 lines for each variable?

Maybe someone can give me a hint how to use map on my RDD. I was thinking of something like this:

```
df.map(lambda (k, v): (v[0], v[0-vEND]))
```

PS: The original post on how I created my initial RDD can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117391/pyspark-read-map-and-reduce-from-multiline-record-textfile-with-newapihadoopfi).

Comment: Something like this (I dont have any pyspark at hand) ? `df.map(lambda i : (i[0], i[1:]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a list of list of items and not tuple

Try this:

```
df.map(lambda i : (i[0], i[1:]))
```

For the `i[1:]` part , look up for slicing in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)