# Pyspark: Reading JSON data file with no separator between objects

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a kinesis firehose delivery stream that puts data to S3. However in the data file the json objects has no separator between it. So it looks something like this,

```
{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2"
}{
  "key1" : "value1",
  "key2" : "value2"
}
```

In Apache Spark I am doing this to read the data file,

```
df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(path, multiLine=True)
```

This can read only the first json object in the file and the rest neglected because there is no seperator.

How can I use resolve this issue in spark?

Comment: Fix the upstream process? Anything you'll do in Spark will be at least somewhat inefficient and ugly.

Comment: makes sense. but i would like to know the rdd based approach to solve this. or if there is any better approach ofcourse.

Comment: Off the top of my head: you can use `wholTextFiles` and parse manually - but it is bad performance wise. You can try to use [Hadoop Input format with delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227363/6910411) if structure is always delimited by `}{`, and then fix records, but it is hack. You can implement your own input format, but not in Python, and it is a lot of code for such a problem. But honestly - if process is under your control, don't waste time on fixing the symptoms, fix the problem :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sparkContext`'s `wholeTextFiles` api to read the *json file* into `Tuple2(filename, whole text)`, *parse the whole text to multiLine jsons*, and then finally use `sqlContext` to read it as *json to dataframe*.

```
sqlContext\
    .read\
    .json(sc
          .wholeTextFiles("path to your multiline json file")
          .values()
          .flatMap(lambda x: x
                   .replace("\n", "#!#")
                   .replace("{#!# ", "{")
                   .replace("#!#}", "}")
                   .replace(",#!#", ",")
                   .split("#!#")))\
    .show()
```

you should get `dataframe` as

```
+------+------+
|  key1|  key2|
+------+------+
|value1|value2|
|value1|value2|
+------+------+
```

You can modify the code according to your need though

Comment: Hi, my data is structured as follows, what might you recommend if I wanted restaurant id as values in one column, latitude and longitude in other columns? Thanks! ===>   

[{"restaurant_id": "1234", "infos": [{"timestamp": "2020-02-03T00:57:26.000Z", "longitude": "-123, "latitude": "456"}{"restaurant_id": "5678", "infos":[{"timestamp": "2....

Comment: Really helpful. Worked like charm. Thanks