# PySpark read in a big customized line ending file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, line-endings

The file is 20 GB, the line ending char is ␀. Below are PySpark code:

```py
text_file = sc.textFile(file_name)
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("␀"))
counts.count()
```

The error as below:
Too many bytes before newline: 2147483648

Question: How to use PySpark read in a big customized line ending file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same technique as in [creating spark data structure from multiline record](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31227363/8371915)

```py
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    '/tmp/weird',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': '␀'}
).values()
```