# How to match/extract multi-line pattern from file in pysark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge file of rdf triplets (subject predicate objects) as shown in the image below. The goals it extract the bold items and have the following output

```
  Item_Id | quantityAmount | quantityUnit | rank
    -----------------------------------------------
      Q31      24954         Meter       BestRank
      Q25       582         Kilometer    NormalRank
```

[image]

I want to extract lines that follow the following pattern

- subject is given a pointer (`<Q31> <prop/P1082> <Pointer_Q31-87RF> .`)
- Pointer has a ranking (`<Pointer_Q31-87RF> <rank> <BestRank>` )
  and valuePointer (`<Pointer_Q31-87RF> <prop/Pointer_value/P1082> <value/cebcf9>` )
- The valuePointer in turn points to its Amount (`<value/cebcf9> <quantityAmount> "24954"`)  and Unit (`<value/cebcf9> <quantityUnit> <Meter>`)

The normal way is to read the file line by line and extract each one of these above patterns (using sc.textFile('inFile').flatMap(lambda x: extractFunc(x)) and then through different joins combine them such that it would provide the above table. 
Is there a better way to go after this? I am including the file sample below.

```
<Q31> <prop/P1082> <Pointer_Q31-87RF> .
<Pointer_Q31-87RF> <rank> <BestRank> .
<Pointer_Q31-87RF> <prop/Pointer_P1082> "+24954"^^<2001/XMLSchema#decimal> .
<Pointer_Q31-87RF> <prop/Pointer_value/P1082> <value/cebcf9> .
<value/cebcf9> <syntax-ns#type> <QuantityValue> .
<value/cebcf9> <quantityAmount> 24954
<value/cebcf9> <quantityUnit> <Meter> .
<Q25> <prop/P1082> <Pointer_Q25-8E6C> .
<Pointer_Q25-8E6C> <rank> <NormalRank> .
<Pointer_Q25-8E6C> <prop/Pointer_P1082> "+24954”
<Pointer_Q25-8E6C> <prop/Pointer_value/P1082> <value/cebcf9> .
<value/cebcf9> <syntax-ns#type> <QuantityValue> .
<value/cebcf9> <quantityAmount> "582" .
<value/cebcf9> <quantityUnit> <Kilometer> .
```

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227363/creating-spark-data-structure-from-multiline-record. For example, in your sample data, you can read your data in paragraph-mode by setting up delimiter = '\n\n' so that all related lines will be read in the same RDD element.

Comment: my bad, there is \n\n, I did it for better readability.

Comment: can you use `\n<Q` as delimiter?

Comment: The order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use `\n<Q` as the delimiter to create RDD elements, then it becomes a pure python task to parse the data blocks. Below I create a function (based on your sample) to parse the block texts using regexes and retrieve cols information into Row object (you might have to adjust the regexes to reflect the actual data patterns, i.e. case sensitivity, extra white spaces etc.):

- For each RDD element, split by '\n' (line-mode)
- and then for each line, split by `> <` into a list `y`
- we can find `rank`, `quantityUnit` by checking *y[1]* and *y[2]*, `quantityAmount` by checking *y[1]* and `Item_id` by checking *y[0]*.
- Create Row object by iterating all required fields, set value to None for missing fields

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import Row
  import re

  # skipped the code to initialize SparkSession

  # field names to retrieve
  cols = ['Item_Id', 'quantityAmount', 'quantityUnit', 'rank']

  def parse_rdd_element(x, cols):
      try:
          row = {}
          for e in x.split('\n'):
              y = e.split('> <')
              if len(y) < 2:
                  continue
              if y[1] in ['rank', 'quantityUnit']:
                  row[y[1]] = y[2].split(">")[0]
              else:
                  m = re.match(r'^quantityAmount>\D*(\d+)', y[1])
                  if m:
                      row['quantityAmount'] = m.group(1)
                      continue
                  m = re.match('^(?:<Q)?(\d+)', y[0])
                  if m:
                      row['Item_Id'] = 'Q' + m.group(1)
          # if row is not EMPTY, set None to missing field
          return Row(**dict([ (k, row[k]) if k in row else (k, None) for k in cols])) if row else None
      except:
          return None
  ```

setup RDD using newAPIHadoopFile() with `\n<Q` as delimiter:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(
    '/path/to/file',
    'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable',
    'org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
    conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter': '\n<Q'}
)
```

Use the map function to parse the RDD element into Row object

```
rdd.map(lambda x: parse_rdd_element(x[1], cols)).collect()
#[Row(Item_Id=u'Q31', quantityAmount=u'24954', quantityUnit=u'Meter', rank=u'BestRank'),
# Row(Item_Id=u'Q25', quantityAmount=u'582', quantityUnit=u'Kilometer', rank=u'NormalRank')]
```

Convert the above RDD to dataframe

```
df = rdd.map(lambda x: parse_rdd_element(x[1], cols)).filter(bool).toDF()
df.show()
+-------+--------------+------------+----------+
|Item_Id|quantityAmount|quantityUnit|      rank|
+-------+--------------+------------+----------+
|    Q31|         24954|       Meter|  BestRank|
|    Q25|           582|   Kilometer|NormalRank|
+-------+--------------+------------+----------+
```

**Some Notes:**

- For better performance, pre-compile all regex patterns using *`re.compile()`* before passing them to the parse_rdd_element() function.
- In case there could be spaces/tabs between `\n` and `<Q`, multiple blocks will be added into the same RDD element, just split the RDD element by `\n\s+<Q` and replace `map()` with `flatMap()`.

**Reference**: [creating spark data structure from multiline record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227363/creating-spark-data-structure-from-multiline-record)

Comment: I like the approach but as I said earlier in the comments, I have no way to know if the order shown above is always preserved in the large file.

Comment: hi, @user1848018, what do you mean by `order`? can you actually split the text file by using `\n<Q` or `\n\s+<Q` and keep related lines into the same RDD element? if so, then all problems left are just parsing texts. Unless you can add all typical text layout, there is really nothing I can help. BTW. the current method does not rely on the order of these fields, as long as they are in their own lines.

Comment: By order I mean, what if Q31> <prop/P1082> <Pointer_Q31-87RF> .

Comment: @user1848018, I only saw a missing `<`, what does that mean? or some specific substring must be shown in text matching? BTW. Is it possible that lines related to `<Q31>` mess up with lines related to `<Q25>`, if that is the truth, then will need a completely different approach.

Comment: BTW. as long as you can use a delimiter like `\n<Q` to split the text files with all **related texts** in the **same** RDD element. for example, one RDD element might contain multiple text blocks i.e. <Q31>, <Q25> which might be from a missing `<` or extra spaces. we can split the RDD using re.split() later and then run flatMap()